# apt-get source is giving me old version of postfix

Tags: postfix, apt

I tried to apply VDA patch to postfix, but I see that my installed version is 2.9.6 installed via apt-get install. While when I try to get source apt-get source, it gave me 2.9.1.

So what is happening here?

[image]

source.list file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your apt configuration isn't consistent between binary packages and source packages.

Have a look in /etc/apt/sources.list (and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*) and make sure there is a 'deb-src' line for each 'deb' line, and that the suite (ie the release codename: wheezy, stable, precise, percise-update, etc) is the same for both 'deb' and 'deb-src'. Then update the package information by `apt-get update` and then you should get version 2.9.6 when you `apt-get source postfix`.

Comment: Hey, but everything source.list file seems fine. I updated OP with that info.

Comment: Ahh, but you don't have deb-src lines for security and updates, try adding them

Comment: Yep adding them helped. But I wouldn't imagine correct version would be in Security/Updates repo.